# Excel AVERAGE() Returning Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Excel Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiXft.png)

Hi, I'm just not sure why the AVERAGE() function is returning a date. Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Format resulting column as number or general.

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning a date.  It's returning an integer, and you have that column configured to display as a date.  Use Ctrl-1 to set the format of that cell to "General".